# PHP fatal error after installing SilverStripe comments module

Tags: php, postgresql, silverstripe

I installed the comments module from http://www.silverstripe.org/comments-module/ (v 1.0.0.) using SS 3.0.5. on Ubuntu with PostgreSQL as database. I copied the extracted folder to the root folder of my SS instance and did a rebuild without getting any error messages. Afterwards I got a "Server error - Sorry, there was a problem handling your request." and the error message displayed at the bottom of this post in my error.log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Markus

```
[Mon Apr 08 08:26:45 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error: Couldn't 
run query: SELECT DISTINCT "SiteTree_Live"."ClassName", "SiteTree_Live"."Create 
d", "SiteTree_Live"."LastEdited", "SiteTree_Live"."URLSegment", "SiteTree_Live". 
"Title", "SiteTree_Live"."MenuTitle", "SiteTree_Live"."Content", "SiteTree_Live" 
."MetaTitle", "SiteTree_Live"."MetaDescription", "SiteTree_Live"."MetaKeywords", 
"SiteTree_Live"."ExtraMeta", "SiteTree_Live"."ShowInMenus", "SiteTree_Live"."Sh
owInSearch", "SiteTree_Live"."Sort", "SiteTree_Live"."HasBrokenFile", "SiteTree_ 
Live"."HasBrokenLink", "SiteTree_Live"."ReportClass", "SiteTree_Live"."CanViewTy 
pe", "SiteTree_Live"."CanEditType", "SiteTree_Live"."ProvideComments", "SiteTree 
_Live"."Version", "SiteTree_Live"."ParentID", "SiteTree_Live"."ID", CASE WHEN "S 
iteTree_Live"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" ELSE 'Sit 
eTree' END AS "RecordClassName" FROM "SiteTree_Live" WHERE ("URLSegment" = 'them 
es' AND "ParentID" = 0) ORDER BY "SiteTree_Live"."Sort" ASC LIMIT 1 | ERROR: co 
lumn SiteTree_Live.ProvideComments does not exist\nLINE 1 in /var/www/aep-ss/fra 
mework/model/Database.php on line 693
```

Comment: Case sensitivity issue from inconsistent quoting? What's the definition of the table? Please show the output of `\d SiteTree_Live` and `\d "SiteTree_Live"` from `psql`.

Comment: Have a look at the installation docs to see if there is anything you missed: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/blob/master/docs/en/Installing.md

Comment: 3dgoo: Thanks, I reinstalled using composer as it is described in the link you sent and it worked. It seems to me that the 1.0.0 release that I downloaded from http://www.silverstripe.org/comments-module/ had a bug regarding postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.0.0 release of the SilverStripe comments module available as download from http://www.silverstripe.org/comments-module/ has a bug in regard to its postgreSQL support. An installation using composer with the following steps will install a current, fixed version (source: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/blob/master/docs/en/Installing.md):

Edit your project-wide composer.json file as follows; in the "require" block add:

```
"silverstripe/comments": "*"
```

Then in the root of your project run:

```
> composer update silverstripe/comments
```